# CircuitLab is broken

Tags: support, bug, status-review, circuitlab

I've tried it on various computers, fresh browsers, incognito mode, etc., and CircuitLab just doesn't work. Any attempt to edit an existing schematic ends up on an error page.

As an aside, perhaps CircuitLab could be persuaded to open the source to their now-abandonware? There's plenty of small improvements that could be done in that tool. It has been stagnant for years now.

Comment: I'll have someone look into it, it's probably related to imgur issues

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps similar issue has popped up before. In the editable view of the post with the problematic CircuitLab schematic, there may be a line that begins

`![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/...`

If you change that to

`![schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/...`

your problem may go away. (note the change from "https" to "http"). This is at least a work-around.